# How do I remove these extra panels after enabling twinview?

Tags: gnome, twinview

I tried to get TwinView working but in the end all I got is this.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/anzMT.png]

On my way to TwinView I have modified /etc/X11/xorg.conf but right know it looks like this.

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 295.33  (buildd@zirconium)  Fri Mar 30 13:43:34 UTC 2012

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "AUO"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 75.0
    VertRefresh     60.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce 8600M GT"
EndSection

        Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Seems like gnome thinks i have 5 screens connected, or something like that. Does anyone know how to remove the additional panels?

Comment: Please tell us what version of Ubuntu you are running. Edit your question and add this information.

Comment: sorry, I'm running 12.04

Answer (score 1):

*You didn't mention your Ubuntu version, but here is how to remove the panels:*

### 11.04 and earlier:

- Right click on the panel you want to remove and click "Delete This Panel".

### 11.10 and up:

- Hold <kbd>alt</kbd>.
- Right click on the panel and click "Delete This Panel".

---

As for Twinview, only use the official Nvidia tool to enable it.

[image: Nvidia Settings]

Comment: AWESOME, that worked well, I expected something like, "you have to go to /crypticFolder/crypticFolder/crypticFolder/crypticFile.conf and change the crypticValue to 42" Thanks a lot. Btw I used the NvidiaTool and this was the result of the "save xconf" Button, so I dug deeper.

Comment: @roflmau: I'm glad it worked for you. If it did, you can mark the question as solved by clicking the tick next to my answer. Your problem with so many monitors sounds like a bug as I don't see anything wrong with your config file.

Comment: ick, none of these work any more